# What does 'target_link_libraries' do when the target is a static library and the target link is a static library too?

Tags: c++, cmake, static, lib

From the following example:

CMakeList.txt file:

```make
include_directories(inc)  

# Grab all the cpp and h files to be compile. 
file(GLOB SOURCES
    inc/*.h
    inc/*.hpp
    src/*.cpp
)

add_library(MyStaticLib STATIC ${SOURCES} )


target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib PUBLIC  "${OPENCV_LIBS}/opencv_world410.lib" )
target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib PUBLIC  "${OPENCV_LIBS}/opencv_world410d.lib" )
```

Does this create a single static library? I thought you could not link a static library to a static library in c++? Why does this work?
Also, what would be the best way to do this? For example, if I create an API that is a static Lib i.e., MyStaticLib and it’s dependent on opencv’s Static lib, what would be the best way to set this up in CMake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In short

When `target_link_libraries` is applied to the static library, it won't affect on the resulted library **file**. But it affects on the **target** in the similar way, as it would affect on the target of the shared library.

So, you can use `target_link_libraries` both for static and shared libraries in the same manner.

### In details

When applied to the **static** library, `target_link_libraries` doesn't have immediate effect on the creation of this library. That is, when static library will be created (as **file**), it won't store that linkage:

```
add_library(MyStaticLib STATIC ${SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib PUBLIC  "${OPENCV_LIBS}/opencv_world410.lib")
# When file 'MyStaticLib.lib' will be created,
# it will NOT be linked with 'opencv_world410.lib'.
```

(As you probably know, a static library doesn't store any information about the linkage, a static library is just a collection of object files.)

But while the file with the static library doesn't store linkage information, the CMake **target**, which represents that static library, will be "**aware of linkage**". This can be useful in many cases:

1. If in the same project you create an **executable** or a **shared library**, and link it with the static library (using `target_link_libraries`), that executable will actually linked with the dependent library:

   ```
   add_executable(myExe ...)
   target_link_libraries(myExe PRIVATE MyStaticLib)
   # When file 'myExe.exe' will be created, it WILL be linked with 'opencv_world410.lib'
   ```
2. If in the same project you create **another static library**, and link it with the static one, the another static library will be "aware of linkage" both with the initial static library and its dependency.

   ```
   add_library(MyStaticLibAnother STATIC ..)
   target_link_libraries(MyStaticLibAnother PUBLIC MyStaticLib)
   # "As if" following line is executed
   # target_link_libraries(MyStaticLibAnother PUBLIC  "${OPENCV_LIBS}/opencv_world410.lib")
   ```
3. If you **install** your library target and **export** it using command `install(TARGETS ... EXPORT ...)`, then the library can be found with `find_package`. And that `find_package` will create a static library target, which will **be aware of linkage** with all its dependencies:

   ```
   # [In main project]
   install(TARGETS MyStaticLib EXPORT MyProject)
   install(EXPORT MyProject NAMESPACE MyProject::)
   ```

   ```
   # [In another project]
   find_package(MyProject REQUIRED)
   # It creates the target MyProject::MyStaticLib which is
   # "aware of linkage" with 'opencv_world410.lib'.
   ```

Additionally, if you link a static library with a **target** (not with a plain file), and that target contains compile definitions or other information, applicable to the compile stage, the static library will be **compiled** using that compile information.