# CMake: How to compile a static library in a project that only compiles a shared library?

Tags: c, cmake, build, static, rockchip

[This repo](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp) contains the source code to build a library called `librockchip_mpp` that is necessary to access the video processing unit of Rockchip SoCs. The library is a dependency of [this FFmpeg fork](https://github.com/hbiyik/FFmpeg) that enables hardware video acceleration on the rockchip platform. I try to build a static version of this FFmpeg fork and therefore need to build a static version of `librockchip_mpp`. However, the rockchip mpp repo just builds a shared library.

Therefore I tried to change the `CMakeLists.txt` files of the repo. I deleted some unit tests that are not necessary to build the library, deleted a library for legacy rockchip SoCs (`librockchip_vpu`), and tried to change the build process from shared to static. I uploaded my changes [here](https://github.com/MarcA711/mpp). And [here](https://github.com/rockchip-linux/mpp/compare/develop...MarcA711:mpp:develop) you can see the diffs of my fork vs the original repo.

The most important file is `mpp/CMakelists.txt`. Here the `librockchip_mpp` library gets added. Before it was a shared library, I changed that to static.

However, the `librockchip_mpp.a` I receive after compiling contains lots of undefined references, for example this function (executed from the build directory):

```
# nm mpp/librockchip_mpp.a | grep mpp_frame_deinit
                   U mpp_frame_deinit
```

Which is weird, because the function is defined in this static library called `libmpp_base.a`:

```
# nm mpp/base/libmpp_base.a | grep mpp_frame_deinit
                   U mpp_frame_deinit
  00000000000001b0 T mpp_frame_deinit
```

And in the file `mpp/CMakelists.txt` I call `target_link_libraries` this way (`${MPP_STATIC}` refers to the `librockchip_mpp.a` library I try to correctly build, `mpp_base` refers to the `libmpp_base.a` library that always was a static library and works correctly I think):

```
target_link_libraries(${MPP_STATIC} mpp_codec mpp_hal mpp_vproc ${ASAN_LIB}
                      ${BEGIN_WHOLE_ARCHIVE} mpp_base ${END_WHOLE_ARCHIVE})
```

So why is this symbol undefined?

I spent a lot time in the past few weeks and tried everything that I found online, but I wasn't able to build a working static `librockchip_mpp.a` library. I hope that someone who is more familiar with CMake than me is kind enough to help me get it working.

Comment: Creation of a static library doesn't involve a linking step. That is, it is perfectly correct that `librockchip_mpp.a` library doesn't define symbol `mpp_frame_deinit`, which is defined in other library `libmpp_base.a`. For use `librockchip_mpp.a` one should link not only with that library, but with `libmpp_base.a` library too. This is a feature of static libraries in whole, not a CMake-specific.

Comment: I managed to compile FFmpeg with your explaination. However, what is the point of calling `target_link_libraries` on a static library? I have seen this multiple times in other projects.

Comment: "However, what is the point of calling `target_link_libraries` on a static library?" - See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341232/what-does-target-link-libraries-do-when-the-target-is-a-static-library-and-the