# How does a target in CMake implicitly links with lib target, even if I place PRIVATE?

Tags: c++, cmake

[Here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/?compressed=CYSw5gTghgDgFgAgEQDMoGMAuB7CIoA2A%2BjBAKZIIDeAsAFAB22wZCA2vQgitg5gM4gAXqwC8yAIwAmJPQC6Abnr8ArgCNIsROgIr%2BmMhAAyZMGQbBqnBAShqyBBOKQmzFpErpd02AricIarboANaeXGTAZuwI%2BgCeBGIIIAwAbiD8CIrWiW7AAHLMZAAMMbb2js4AogAeZOgqmHaJSAA0sXCwSaZgWeE2puYFRRJldg4BSADKTZgg6AhGIGrQEHFtHV0B2FhQYLx9OYMWhSxSYxWTU53klksrUGsb-J0wScDY6ok7TfsMh14BnlTmQAMwXCbOACyzBUiUWy1W63aLy24kweBg312fwBXFyQxBABYIZVkABJPiGNDoVj3JHPV5JN58PYHbKAgknIoAVlJkwA8moAFb1TAIh5PFFMgJwMg1Nn-Dn447DFgANn5zgAqgwQkwAO7-emPZGbN4BfhkGC-dn9LlqsgAdi1yAAwnocABbBAAFUeZkwjLRgWwNTxQMJRVKAFoAHyR7ksUZsWKYBJJfi%2BECWZWJx2xhMOkHnVPxeHiLMEHMR4vRhDx-Mg0H21Ug0aNussEmp8qQilUiA0igo9MVhDAKAvSK1ttFc6ducsPm98ZkpAABTwqSgBmeY-e2EwBlzreBRXBi-PGpi5cz2dPR2vJQbRaXzs8AF9rFwkEwWMUlCrpczgfFgZD6AAOgwAAUYEGPoABciHwRBmAAJTBha4gsraSr9L%2B-5kBIQE2GukyofoRAGiAmBwEQXpQCk0FwT8aHIZRmDUbR9GMSkmHSiGPyKhGhEjJQjZ-tGlAIAA9LJE5sVRNF0QxTH-I2nE-sgREyK6qAYDgeCEFh3RgL0eZiSwoKkX2640kZ%2BDENWaimdsOJ2tpUnWRJCbecRpF3gEHzHjOchyQpDm4E5RAua%2BingcpPFqSkXm6b5OkXoFB7BUeJ5ZBF3CGdFhDxVFxnOcsaVFEStnkc45UxQhAhueIPSiZl3YZf5Nm3jl4ghfl4XyUVWAlcQzWZI2jWELFVV0N%2BdBAA) you can see my project graph dependencies. So in factorial_tests I use doctest::doctest_with_main library, in factorial_lib I don't use it.In factorial_tests' include directories I placed include directories of doctest lib, but I didn't linked them together. Instead of this, I linked doctest::doctest_with_main to factorial_lib with PRIVATE, so anyone, who links to factorial_lib doesn't need to link doctest::doctest_with_main. Then I linked factorial_tests with factorial_lib but not with doctest. I thought that it'll cause a linking error, because I didn't link factorial_tests with doctest::doctest_with_main.

Here I provided these targets

```
FACTORIAL_LIB
add_library(factorial_lib factorial.cpp)
...
target_link_libraries(factorial_lib PRIVATE doctest::doctest_with_main)
```

```
FACTORIAL_TESTS
add_executable(factorial_tests sometests.cpp)
target_include_directories(factorial_tests DIRECTORY_TO_DOCTEST_INCLUDE_FILES)
target_link_libraries(factorial_lib) #DIDN'T LINK WITH DOCTEST_WITH_MAIN
```

And my projects structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt #Here I have main factorial target and I add subdirectories of doctest and factorial_lib
doctest/
factorial_lib/ 
--tests/ #Sources to factorial_tests target
--CMakeLists.txt #Here I have factorial_lib and factorial_tests targets
--factorial.cpp
--factorial.h
```

So I expected, that it'll cause some linking error, because I didn't linked factorial_tests target with lib, that factorial_tests use. Maybe it's because doctest_with_main target has some interface or public properties?

Comment: `factorial_lib` is a **static** library and can be linked with none of (other) library files, CMake propagates such linkage to the **consumers** of `factorial_lib`. See [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343612/3440745) for more detailed description. Note, that such linkage is performed **irrespective** of PRIVATE/PUBLIC keywords being used. Those keywords are for propagating include directories and other non-file properties of the library target. So, instead of `target_include_directories(factorial_tests DIRECTORY_TO_DOCTEST_INCLUDE_FILES)` you are better to use PUBLIC linkage.